# Getting java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition when trying to replace String with replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the words from the given string with regex

```
{{ some | value }}
```

like this.

for example :

```
Hello {{ some | value }}, this is what i tried {{ another | value }}
```

from this i want to extract

```
{{ some | value }} and {{ another | value }}
```

I tried with this regex pattern `Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}")`

when i tried to iterate all the matches and replace using `replaceAll` i got `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`. Please help me to overcome this issue .

My code

```
Pattern pattern                     = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher matcher                     = pattern.matcher(text);
 while(matcher.find()){
            matches.add(matcher.group());
        }

for (String match : matches) 
{
    match = match.substring(2 , match.length()-2); // I WANT TO GET ONLY SOME | VALUE FROM THE PATTERN
    String splitArray[] = match.split("\\|");
    String value1 = splitArray[0].trim();
    String value2 = splitArray[1].trim();
    text = text.replaceAll(match , value1);
}
```

Comment: It does not look right, please post the whole code. If you escaped the `{` and `}` the way they are in the question, there should not be such an error.

Comment: it works fine...

Comment: updated the question with my code

Comment: I think you mean `String splitArray[] = m.split("\\|");` instead of `String splitArray[] = match.split("\\|");`

Comment: It does not compile: local `match` in `for` loop variable cannot be declared since it is already declared int he `for`.

Comment: I couldn't get it @YCF_L

Comment: See https://ideone.com/kY8E8U. Actually, are you just trying to get a hashmap of word_before_| and word_after_|?

Comment: @siva what you the output should look like?

Comment: It works, I am not able to reproduce your error

Comment: Sorry mistakenly put the wrong variable name in the replaceAll() now corrected its still throwing the issue "text = text.replaceAll(value1 , value1);" to text = text.replaceAll(match , value1);

Comment: @siva Do you just need to replace all `{{...|...}}` with the `value` part? See [**this Java demo**](https://ideone.com/dRwpWa), does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The fix you need is to replace `text = text.replaceAll(match , value1);` with

```
text = text.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(match), Matcher.quoteReplacement(value1));
```

It will replace the first occurrence of `match` with `value1` where both `match` and `value1` are literal strings.

However, I believe you want to replace all `{{...|...}}` with the key part, without actually collecting all the matches/captures. Then, use

```
text.replaceAll("\\{\\{\\s*((?:(?!\\{\\{)[^|])*?)\\s*\\|\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}\\}", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeKOWO/3).

**Details**

- `\{\{` - a `{{` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!\{\{)[^|])*?)` - Group 1: any char other than `|`, 0 or more but as few as possible repetitions, not starting a `{{` sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\|` - a `|`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\}\}` - a `}}` substring.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bdPNEZ):

```
String text = "Hello {{ some | value }}, this is what i tried {{ another | value }}";
text = text.replaceAll("\\{\\{\\s*((?:(?!\\{\\{)[^|])*?)\\s*\\|\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}\\}", "$1");
System.out.println(text);
// => Hello some, this is what i tried another
```

Note that you still can use `Matcher#find()` to extract capturing group values if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using seems needlessly complicated. Looking at your code, it seems you want to replace `{{ some | value }}` with `some` and `{{ another | value }]` with `another` and so on. So why not just do it like this?

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\{\\{ (.+?) \\| .+? \\}\\}", "$1");
```

This will match all instances `{{ ... | ... }}` and replace it with the part between `{{` and `|`.